# Preventing the selection of the first element multiple times by entering ENTER with select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

```
<select style="width:100%;" id="element_dropdown"  multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">First</option>
      <option value="2">Second</option>
      <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

$('#element_dropdown).select2({
      closeOnSelect: true,
      placeholder: "Select an element",
      width: '100%',
      templateResult: formatFunction,
      formatResult: formatFunction,
      formatSelection: formatFunction,
 });
```

Is there a way to do this. I am using select2 3.5. Everytime I click enter, the first element is added several times when allowing for multiple values. I noticed all of my dropdowns do this.

The only solution I found for this was to add  `minimumInputLength: 2`, but it prevents me from quickly selecting any of the options without typing a character.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `openOnEnter: false` option?

```js
$('#element_dropdown').select2({
      placeholder: "Select an element",
      width: '100%',
      openOnEnter: false
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.js"></script>

<select style="width:100%;" id="element_dropdown" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, but I have to click on the field to add an element with enter. It selects the first element by default on focus.

Comment: I am wondering if you can prevent a duplicate from being added by using selecting event handler.

Comment: The problem is that the first one is selected by default.